# How to identify case activities in find activities or advanced search

Tags: civicase, activities, search

In Activity Detail Reports I can set a filter to include or exclude case activities.

Is there a way of filtering activity searches in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 1):

The custom search called Activity Search shouldn't be too hard to update. (See Find - Custom Searches - Activity Search. The file is CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ActivitySearch.php.) It already includes some partial case-awareness.

In fact, if you run it and then select all records, and then from the actions dropdown choose export contacts (yes, contacts), it will then export the activity records and there'll be an unnamed column that has the case id. There's 3 unnamed columns - the last one is case id, and it's blank if it's not a case activity.

Comment: Thank you. This is useful to know. We work predominantly in Drupal so I'm guessing  views are probably the best way of getting to this information. Just wondering if there was anything in the user interface I'd missed. (Not really a coder)